# How to get a scanner to loop until it reads a desired string?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
        Scanner one = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Name: ");
        name = one.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Date of Birth: ");
        dateofbirth = one.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Address: ");
        address = one.nextLine();  
        System.out.print("Enter Gender: ");
        gender = //not sure what to do now
```

Hi I've tried to figure this out myself but I can't quite get it from looking at other examples, most are either only accepting certain characters or A-Z+a-z

I'm trying to make the program only accept input of male or female ignoring the case and if the input is wrong to repeat the "Enter Gender:" until a correct value is entered.

Comment: I don't find ```java.util.Scanner``` that useful for parsing interactive (human) input. I have used the ```java.io.BufferedReader.readLine()```+ ```while```loops.

Comment: How do you not find `java.util.Scanner` useful for parsing input?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put the piece of code in a while and validate each time. for instance:

```
String gender;
do
{
  System.out.print("Enter Gender ('male' or 'female'): ");
  gender = one.nextLine().toLowercase();
} while(!gender.equals("male") && !gender.equals("female"))
```

Comment: *"I'm trying to make the program only accept input of male or female ignoring the case"*

Comment: Fixed. Sorry, forgot that part.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I don't suppose you could explain to me how those while statements work? If the gender is equal to neither male nor female it returns back to the top of the loop(do)?, could you add say '&& !gender.equals("m")' also into the while statement so that if just m is typed it is accepted?

Comment: Well, that is very basic java, you might want to read a tutorial or two ;-)   But very quickly: if whatever condition is inside the while is true, then it loops again. The condition itself is just logic son you can add more conditions with the and (&&) operator at will. '&& !gender.equals("m")' will indeed work.

Comment: Tutorial on do while statements or something else? Thanks for your help by the way

Comment: Flow control in general I guess. Not sure what you know or not, but check this as a good refresher with examples: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html

Answer (score 2):

```
do {
    System.out.print("Enter Gender (M/F): ");
    gender = one.nextLine();
} while (!gender.equalsIgnoreCase("M") && !gender.equalsIgnoreCase("F"));
```

You can add an if check after gender assignment to display a invalid message

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use infinite loop and a label to break out.
Like this:

```
//Start 
Scanner one = new Scanner(System.in);
here:
while (true){
System.out.print("Enter Gender: ");
    String str = one.nextLine();
        switch (str.toUpperCase()){
            case "MALE":
                System.out.println("Cool");
                break here;
            case "FEMALE":
                System.out.println("Nice");
                break here;
            default:
                System.out.println("Genders variants: Male/Female");
      }
}
```

Comment: This recreates the `Scanner` every time the loop runs, which may not give the intended results. Better to put the `Scanner one = new Scanner(System.in)` _outside_ the loop.

Answer (score 1):

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Name: ");
    String name = readValue(scanner, null);
    System.out.print("Enter Date of Birth: ");
    String dateofbirth = readValue(scanner, null);
    System.out.print("Enter Address: ");
    String address = readValue(scanner, null);
    System.out.print("Enter Gender: ");
    String gender = readValue(scanner, createGenderMatcher());
}

private static IMatcher createGenderMatcher() {
    return new IMatcher() {
        @Override
        public boolean isMatch(String value) {
            return "male".equalsIgnoreCase(value) || "female".equalsIgnoreCase(value);
        }
    };
}

private static String readValue(Scanner scanner, IMatcher matcher) {
    String value = null;
    do {
        value = scanner.nextLine();
    } while (matcher != null && !matcher.isMatch(value));
    return value;
}

private interface IMatcher {
    public boolean isMatch(String value);
}
```